# Calling a specific view controller with a custom button class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, viewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

everyone. I have a profile button of a custom class that is meant to present a ProfileViewController once clicked. The **ProfileButton inherits from UIButton, and appears on the navigation bars of several view controllers**. While I'm aware that I can add a function to each VC's code, I prefer to do this in a more elegant way. What I've tried so far is:-

1. Calling the ProfileViewController from within the ProfileButton class: I can't reference the ProfileViewController using storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.
2. Using a delegate: This still means adding code to each VC. Thanks in advance.

I've posted the code for the button class. I'm looking for a way to place the code in a single location that still achieves this result.

```
class ProfileButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.profileButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

    }

}
```

**Edit:-**

The issue isn't presenting or dismissing the VC. I'm simply trying to find the most elegant way to present the ProfileVC using the profile button without adding self.presentViewController(animated: true, completion: nil) to ViewController1, ViewController2, ViewController3, etc.

Here's an image to show how its setup:-

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A46qV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by having a base class for all the View Controllers which have the navigation bar with 'profile' button.

write the profile button action in the base class, and any action from extended classes will invoke the base class method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are wanting to know how to make a screen system, so here is how I normally do this.

I use the property of UIView "isHidden", which shows and hides views. When a view is hidden, the view will not respond to touches (UIGestureRecognizers) that may be attached to the viewController. So when you want to switch to a new view from another viewController, (or the UIButton) just set the current view to be hidden, and set isHidden to false on the new view you want to open.

I also normally make a "show" function that I use to setup the view. Its up to you if you want to use this or a built in function for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, C1FR1. What you're suggesting sounds like I need to add the profile view to each VC, but that would still involve repetition, but this in this case with views. I need a cheaper way to do this than having a function which calls the ProfileVC in the other VCs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a bit fuzzy on your issue. But what I'm hearing is:

- (1) You have multiple views (with view controllers) embedded in a navigation bar.
- (2) There's a profile button on this navigation bar, which is a subclass of UIButton or UIBarButton. (Your code suggests it's UIButton. No matter.)
- (3) When this profile button is tapped, you wish to show a profile view (with it's own view controller) and...? I'll guess that (a) you **do not** want the profile button, and maybe even the navigation bar visible, and (b) you want to return to item #1 when finished.
- (4) Finally, you want to have items #2 and #3 split off from #1. That is, you wish to code for this "profile" mechanism once and only once.

If this is the case, I'd ask myself two things:

- (1) How does Apple do it? Maybe something like a "settings" view inside an app.
- (2) How does another app do it?

My suggestions:

- (1) Can you make your profile view modal? This would be a way to "force" the user to tap something to clear it.
- (2) Can you call the profile view and manipulate the navigation bar appropriately when it's visible? Here I'm thinking either hide the entire bar, or swap out the profile button with another button (which can be done in various ways).

Either way, you've effectively placed all you code in one place, and the only code needed in your individual view controllers is to make sure the navigation bar displayed when their view is visible is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this inside `profileButtonPressed` method

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as? ProfileViewController {
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Implement `topViewController` method like this.

```
extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    return UIApplication.topViewController(base: nil)
}
class func topViewController(base: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    var baseView = base
    if baseView == nil {
        baseView = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController
    }
    if let vc = baseView?.presentedViewController {
        return UIApplication.topViewController(base: vc)
    } else {
        return baseView;
    }
}
}
```

If you want to push into top navigation view, change `topViewController` method to search for top presented navcontroller then current view in it, and then push into it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, RJE. Your approach looks elegant but the only issue is I can't reference a view controller or storyboard from within the button class using UIStoryboard....instantiateVC.